# gRPC "failed to pick subchannel" if server and client are hosted on different machines

Tags: grpc

The server and client connect successfully if using localhost. Here's how I connect to remote server in python:

```
with grpc.insecure_channel('x.x.x.x:50051', options=(('grpc.enable_http_proxy', 0),)) as channel:
```

The server code to set up the port is defined as:

```
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
```

I have tried to change that to "0.0.0.0:50051", but it didn't help. Does someone know the issue here?

Comment: This looks like it may be a generic network connectivity problem, not gRPC specefic. Can you access the remote machine without gRPC in the mix? Check that the server is running, and that the port is open, no firewall rules would be blocking the connection, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even when client and server on the same machine with firewall disabled.
I solved my problem by ensuring the server was not using "localhost". It would not work when server was using localhost and client used the ip address of the PC.
I had to set the host of both client and server to a physical ip address that can be accessed on your network.

Comment: We had the same issue in one of our Docker containers and got around it by using host.docker.internal instead of localhost.